# Backward Compatibility when adding a field in response of an API

Tags: java, serialization, protostuff

I have added a couple of new fields to a Json response of an object .It rus fine when we update the client to hit the API . But older versions of the API give a serialization error. I am using **PROTOSTUFF** to serialize and deserialize the object . How can I make the old version of client to ignore the new fields and continue to work properly .
I have tried making the **fields transient and @JsonIgnore** Tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42847522/parse-json-with-optional-field

Comment: What about [useProtocolVersion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#useProtocolVersion(int))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add the extra fields at the end of all fields in the class instead of in the middle . PROTOSTUFF ignores the fields added at the end as unknown fields and doesn't throw an error .

Answer (score 0):

You need version control in your controller. You must implement a versioning mechanism to figure out which method should be called in witch version... it's near impossible to handle this issue with a single action in the controller.

See below link:

[REST API Versioning](https://restfulapi.net/versioning/)

[Introduction to API Versioning Best Practices](https://nordicapis.com/introduction-to-api-versioning-best-practices/)

Comment: The change is really small with addition of just two extra key-value pair . And Creating versioning for every is a big effort so i was looking for some hack